# could not find module

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I start to test web AR using 8thwall today by following their official tutorial, but I got below error

when I run

```
serve\bin\serve.bat -n -d gettingstarted\xraframe -p 7777
```

for serve my application I got below error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\MyProjects\8th wall tutorial                     
webAR\web\src\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I tried using npm install again and also got that error 
tutorial link : https://docs.8thwall.com/web/#locally-from-windows

Comment: What directory are you in when running the serve script?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(from serve's parent directory) serve\bin\serve.bat -d <path for your project directory>
```

Example:

```
C:\Users\X\web>serve\bin\serve.bat -d C:\Users\X\webar-image-target
```

my **serve** folder resides in **web** folder and my project in **webar-image-target** folder